# Does “Aria the Scarlet Ammo” manga continue off from the anime, or does it turn into the spinoff?

Tags: hidan-no-aria

I'm considering reading *Hidan no Aria* after watching the anime (a long time ago). I remember when the spinoff came instead of season two and was fairly disappointed.

Does the manga continue with the same main characters?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are more than 1 manga series:

1. *Hidan no Aria*: started as a light novel, got adapted into manga & anime.
2. *Hidan no Aria AA*: started as spin-off manga, got adapted into anime & light novel.
3. *Hidan no Aria-chan*: a 4-koma spin-off manga.

So, to answer the question: **yes, *Hidan no Aria* manga continues from the anime, which is an adaptation to the original light novel**. The anime ends at volume 3 of the light novel, which is around volume 8-9 of the manga.

---

Note: *Hidan no Aria* manga continues as *Hidan no Aria - Shiden no Majo* after volume 16.